# Passing an array of unknown shape

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function that I use to duplicate an array:

```
const data = (items) => {
  myData = items.slice()
}
```

Now `items` is an array of objects and these objects can be of any shape. How do I achieve this in TypeScript?

```
const data = (items: Array<any>) => {
```

This works but I am not sure if using any here is the best way.

Comment: Did you _try_ using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)? `T[]` would allow the type to be inferred from what was actually passed in. How is `myData` defined and where is it used?

Comment: it can be anything so generics work thanks

Comment: Generics is something I have not quite got my head around yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), which will allow you to infer the input type

In the following example, I return the copy for demonstration purpose, so you can see what's inferred for the output given `T`

```ts
// T extends unknown restricts[] the parameters to be of array type
const data = <T extends unknown[]>(items: T): T => {
  myData = items.slice()
  return myData;
}

// inferred as number[]
const outputA = data([1, 2, 3])

// inferred as string[]
cont outputB = data(['str1', 'str2'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since in the first call `T` is `number` and doesn't extend `unknown[]`. Did you mean `(items: T)`?

Comment: `T extends unknown[]` isn't needed if `(items: T[])`.

Comment: right, let me edit

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what `myData` is and how you want to use it. I guess you want that function to return the copied array? In that case you can add a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to `data` so the type of the returned array gets inferred from what you pass as a parameter.

```js
const data = <T,>(items: T[]): T[] => {
    return items.slice()
}

const newArray = data([3,4,5])
// const newArray: number[]
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGAeAKgGgHwAUAllAKYC2EAXDFgNoC6AlDfQ2njAN4BQM-MAE6koAV0FgYJChAB0EADZFgpAkx4BfHj1CRYYUgHcAgoMEIAnmnhIEBOgGYcAFhwBWZjAD0XmAZNmljRgouQARqSCjDrg0H4gUKbmVuiIyAQOTN6+GAC0MACiZiCCsjAADgjm5CKRUhDxsAiSVcmyPEA)

Comment: yes it can by anything

Comment: const data = <Type>(items: Type[]) => {

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are really good, but I don't like them for more complex objects since I don't think they do a deep copy, but this does it :

```js
const a = (items: any[]): any[] => {
    const copyArray: any[] = []
    items.forEach((i) => copyArray.push({...i}));
    return copyArray;
}
```

or

```js
const a = (items: any[]): any[] => {
    const copyArray: any[] = []
    items.forEach((i) => copyArray.push(Object.assign({}, i)));
    return copyArray;
}
```

Unfortunately for list strings it's not the best since it will split them into arrays.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0cQAXlAAAp5JBEAUxJw8ABtAC6AEp8mzOVzQDSAHygADeihKJQpVLRBDwFTIZCY-LMguFoG5UulTJZAWS8DIAFEGBp6YyecKxQgFUqVXgAgR2PZ6QB5aQAK0gsFQAQYgjkzE49PFAF9%20BQedGANw6kpOVD4ry2xXKphxsPkxpyhRyukcgBE0ihhf4xYYiDLoGLHCrXLjsupys1HPFDH5hYAjAAmQsRiUdmu9gDM-f47c7o4ALP2G9nKTRpJqGPTHGQeXHFLL4O4AtB4Mw18rN9uc7vIPvD-TpKfFNIOQAGLn%20zWFvtbnd7g9H9enr%20Xj%20N6bkAA)